# Limit fields when marking subsequent options (in one form). Django

Tags: django, forms

I have a very simple form and I would like to restrict it when I select the first field. For example, after selecting a product, the t-shirt is displayed in the 'add_on' field (red, green, gray) and after selecting the field the shoes are displayed (leather, suede).

```
class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = OrderingMassage
        fields = ('product',
                  'add_on')
```

How can this be done in the simplest possible way? any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be using javascript. Use onchange="toggleSomething()" on the field like a checkbox or select. In the script, use show() and hide() on the div that encloses the optional fields depending on the value selected.